тем и есть (syntax and meaning)
Also from Iosif Bikerman's РОССІЯ И ЕВРЕИ 1924:

Правый тѣмъ и есть правый, что онъ не склоненъ къ прыжкамъ, не
склоненъ отрываться отъ своего прошлаго, прошлаго родной страны и
родного народа

тем и есть ... что is my focus here. This is really a syntactical thing. Does it mean "the very reason why a right-winger is right-wing is that he is not given to (mental) leaps"? I've read a lot of Russian, but never seen this тем и есть ... что before.
Another translation: a right-winger is right-wing by dint of the fact that ...

Тем и (short adj), что is an idiomatic construct meaning "that's what makes it":


Вообще-то талантливый ребенок тем и талантлив, что может запросто менять ипостаси: то он отпетый хулиган, а то вдруг — маленький светоч. // [Наталья Склярова. Казаки-разбойники // «Вечерняя Москва», 2002.01.10]
The ability to show different sides of themselves is, actually, what makes a talented kid talented: one moment, they're a hopeless rascal; the next moment, they're a little luminary.

— Рыночная цена тем и хороша, что ее определяет рынок, а не операторы. // [Вам нужны такие скидки? (2002) // «Туринфо», 16.04.2002]
What makes the market price good is the fact that it's being defined by the market and not by the (tour) operators.



The usage in your excerpt is slightly non-standard (using a full adjective with a copula as a predicate, and not a short adjective), but perfectly understandable. The "correct" form would have been *правый тем и прав,  but the adjective правый in its sense of "opposed to left" doesn't form a short adjective, and the short adjective прав always means "correct".
